# select rows if all meets same criteria and only one meets a criteria

Tags: sql

I have a OrdersDetails Table so i want to get the status of the orders based on orders status, when all products are new then status is new, when all products are closed then status is closed, when some product is pending then status is pending.

```
OrderId     |ProductID   |ProductStatus
ORDER1      |PRODUCT1    |NEW
ORDER1      |PRODUCT2    |PENDING
ORDER2      |PRODUCT3    |CLOSED
ORDER2      |PRODUCT4    |CLOSED
ORDER3      |PRODUCT5    |NEW
ORDER3      |PRODUCT6    |NEW
ORDER4      |PRODUCT7    |CLOSED
ORDER4      |PRODUCT8    |PENDING
```

Desired Result Table

```
OrderID  |Status
ORDER1   |PENDING
ORDER2   |CLOSED
ORDER3   |NEW
ORDER4   |PENDING
```

Comment: Which SQL are you using?

Comment: What if you have an order with a mix of NEW and CLOSED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `group by` with `case`:

```
select orderid,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) and min(status) in ('NEW', 'CLOSED')
             then min(status)
             when sum(case when status = 'PENDING' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'PENDING'
             else 'This case is not described in the question'
        end)
from t
group by orderid;
```

Comment: I know you have 347k rep, and this shouldn't surprise me, but it never ceases to amaze me how quickly you type out an answer. I was just finishing out the `end` when you posted.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune . . . I've mentioned before that the most valuable class I took in high school was touch typing.  In college, my favorite was paper-folding polyhedra, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never will get mixed states unless the order is pending, this should work:

```
select OrderId, 'PENDING' Status
from #orderTable
group by OrderId
having COUNT(distinct ProductStatus)>1
union all
select OrderId, MIN(ProductStatus) Status
from #orderTable
group by OrderId
having COUNT(distinct ProductStatus)=1
order by 1
```